# Flex direction row with its content to centre

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I move the content of class ".content" to the centre of its parent class ".primary"?  I did try to set a "width:10px" but it doesn't do anything.  All I want, is for the children "div" of parent class ".primary" to move to its centre with a specific width.  Right now, they spread across its parent width;

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.content {
  flex-grow:1;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item primary"> 
   <div class="content">Content 1 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 2 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Can you not just use `text-align: center;` on the **.content** class?

Comment: The blue border boxes, I want to set a specific width to it and bring to the centre of it parent (the red border around it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align items in a flex container you should use `justify-content`.  That being said, with flex-grow set to 1 your items will ignore your width setting and grow to fill the parent.  Below is an example with the width of 10px and aligned to the center

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item primary"> 
   <div class="content">Content 1 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 2 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have adjusted content `div` width by applying `flex-basis: 20%;` and remove `flex-grow:1;` from `.content` class. The reason here is `flex-grow:1;` grows element width to fullwidth of it's parent element. And also add `justify-content: center;` for `.primary` class, which makes `.content` boxes center aligned.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  /*flex-grow:1;*/
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item primary"> 
   <div class="content">Content 1 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 2 </div>
   <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```